# Delete entity in App Engine Datastore, but it gets restored all the time?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I delete an entity, the admin log tells me it was deleted: "Deleted an entity".

It is gone, atleast for some time, then suddenly the resurrection takes place!

Any ideas what might be happening here? I deleted the same item 4 times now!

It drives me a lil bit crazy :)

Im using the Master/Slave Datastore.

Comment: Switch to HRD, anyway you will have to ;)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have code somewhere else running that is creating the same entity. It could be a task, cron initiated task, a normal web request, etc. You might want to check that.

And yes, SWITCH TO HRD. :)

Comment: nope thats impossible since i can only populate the content trough an android app which is not running! anyways i just migrated to HRD, now i cant read my own blobs anymore :)

Comment: You can't read your own blobs? Blobstore or Datastore? You might want to check on the way you store Keys (Blobstore/Datastore Keys). If you stored them as a string, and not as a KeyProperty, then the migration was not able to re-write them properly. If that's the case, you won't be able to access those data. You'd have to use the new keys.

Comment: actually it tells me that i dont have permission to read them... i opened another question on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308229/migrating-to-hrd-this-application-does-not-have-access-to-that-blob