# migrating to HRD "This application does not have access to that blob"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I just migrated to HRD and now its telling me i cant access my own blobs...

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.SecurityException: This application does not have access to that blob.
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.fetchData(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:200)
at com.droidastic.telljokes.server.servlet.ServeBlobsServlet.checkBlobKeyExists(ServeBlobsServlet.java:100)
at com.droidastic.telljokes.server.servlet.ServeBlobsServlet.doGet(ServeBlobsServlet.java:64)
```

Comment: still driving me crazy... can i revert the alias atleast?! i tried disabling the new version but that didnt help. deletion takes 72 hours...

Comment: I don't think deleting would change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened to me before when I migrated to HRD. I had my keys stored as strings in the datastore, when I migrated, those stringed keys where not re-written. It was quite a nightmare.

Anyway, your blobstore keys were probably not re-written to point to the new keys in your new app in HRD. It could be because you stored them as a string or something other than the equivalent of BlobstoreKey in Java.

Comment: i don't give the blobs their key, the key is assigned automatically, what i set is the blob title, the title is still correct, the blob key is correct and i can see the blobs in the blobviewer. but when i want to access them i get the above exception :/

Comment: @Felix But where are you storing blob keys once they're generated? If you're storing them as strings, as Albert points out, the migration process cannot tell that they're blob keys, and won't update them.

Comment: ohh now i get it :) yes i stored them as a string and then i create them likes this: BlobKey key = new BlobKey(this.params.blobKey); isnt that the intended use :/? how can i recover the blobs?

Comment: I suggest you open another question for that. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458931/how-can-i-recover-blobs-after-migration-to-hrd