# How can i recover Blobs after migration to HRD

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I just migrated to HRD and now its telling me i cant access my own blobs...

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.SecurityException: This application does not have access to that blob.
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.fetchData(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:200)
at com.droidastic.telljokes.server.servlet.ServeBlobsServlet.checkBlobKeyExists(ServeBlobsServlet.java:100)
at com.droidastic.telljokes.server.servlet.ServeBlobsServlet.doGet(ServeBlobsServlet.java:64)
```

I stored the keys as a string inside the datastore entities and then i create them like this:

```
BlobKey key = new BlobKey(this.params.blobKey);
```

How can i recover the blobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
public String getMigratedBlobKey(String oldKey) {
  String migrationEntityKey = "__BlobMigration__";
  Key createKey = KeyFactory.createKey(migrationEntityKey, oldKey);
  Entity migrationEntity = datastore.get(createKey);
  BlobKey newKey = (BlobKey) migrationEntity.getProperty("new_blob_key");
  return newKey.getKeyString();
}

"__BlobMigration__" and "new_blob_key" are GAE constants.
```